# Using Beaglebone black in Window 10

Tags: beagleboneblack

I want to using beaglebone black in IOT.
My OS is window, so I use "Putty" connecting with debian.

IP address is 192.168.7.2, Port 22 and Connection type is SSH.

I want to confirm networking state so enter "ping 192.168.7.1".
Then, putty is not working.
so i adjust entering like "ping -c 2 192.168.7.1".
output is receive 0 and loss 100%.

I don't know the reason why output is like that.
I connect computer by ethernet, and beagle connecting p4.

Answer (score 0):

BBB is configured by default to use the dynamic host configuration protocol DHCP, so ti will get some random IP address if you are using ethernet and not USB. However, you have some options to find it out:

1. You can attach a display and check the IP address asigned to the BBB;
2. You can connect to the BBB via [serial console](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Serial) (although you need a specail cable for it);
3. You can connect your BBB via USB for the first time and configure a static address as described [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/) and [here](http://www.ofitselfso.com/Beagle/NetworkingSetupConnectingTheBeagleboneBlack.php)

Answer (score -1):

Attention, 192.168.7.2 is default BBB ip on Virtual ETH via USB (in Windows). You try connect usb and open SSH on 192.168.7.2:22. If fine, you can to change IP configuration on /etc/network/interfaces